# Multiple emails for each value after filtering data

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

[image]

I have updated below code to send multiple emails to assigned recipients.
I am not able to paste the table into mail and recipients are duplicated.

I need "Column E" to filter and paste that table into email body using email recipient from "column J".

I need separate email for all values in "column E"

```vb
Sub SendMultipleEmailsaa()
    
    Dim Mail_Object, OutApp As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim arr() As Variant
    
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
    
    arr = ws.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
    
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    first = 2
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    
        If i = UBound(arr) Then GoTo YO
        If arr(i + 1, 1) = arr(i, 1) Then
            first = WorksheetFunction.Min(first, i + 1)
        Else
    YO:
            Set OutApp = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
    
            With OutApp
                .Subject = "Your Details"
                .Body = "Please find details below"
                .Display
                .To = ws.Range("J" & i + 1).Value
                For j = first To i
                    .Recipients.Add ws.Range("J" & j).Value
                Next
                first = i + 2
    
            End With
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add recipients and set the `To` field separately in the code:

```
 .To = ws.Range("J" & i + 1).Value
         For j = first To i
            .Recipients.Add ws.Range("J" & j).Value
         Next
```

See [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor).

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

   ```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
   ```
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.